# Как исправить ошибку ,чтобы код работал

Tags: javascript, html, css

Выскакивает ошибка "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

```js
function yey() {
  let count = 0;
  let dv = document.querySelectorAll('.dv')
  if (count < dv.length) {
    dv[count].classList.add('visible')
    count++
    let time = setTimeout(yey(), 1000)
  } else {
    clearTimeout(time)
  }
}
```

```css
.dv { display: none; }

.visible { display: block; }
```

```html
<button class='butt' onclick='yey()'>Button</button>

<div class="dv">eeeeeee</div>
<div class="dv">eeeeeee</div>
<div class="dv">eeeeeee</div>
<div class="dv">eeeeeee</div>
<div class="dv">eeeeeee</div>
<div class="dv">eeeeeee</div>
<div class="dv">eeeeeee</div>
<div class="dv">eeeeeee</div>
<div class="dv">eeeeeee</div>
<div class="dv">eeeeeee</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setTimeout(yey(), 1000)
              ^^ - calling, not passing reference
```

---

```
let count = 0; 
function yey() {
  ...
  setTimeout(yey, 1000);
```

```js
let count = 0;
function yey() {
  let dv = document.querySelectorAll('.dv')
  if (count < dv.length) {
    dv[count++].classList.add('visible')
    setTimeout(yey, 300)
  }
}
```

```css
.dv { display: none; }

.visible { display: block; }
```

```html
<button class='butt' onclick='yey()'>Button</button>

<div class="dv">eeeeeee 1</div>
<div class="dv">eeeeeee 2</div>
<div class="dv">eeeeeee 3</div>
<div class="dv">eeeeeee 4</div>
<div class="dv">eeeeeee 5</div>
<div class="dv">eeeeeee 6</div>
<div class="dv">eeeeeee 7</div>
<div class="dv">eeeeeee 8</div>
<div class="dv">eeeeeee 9</div>
<div class="dv">eeeeeee 10</div>
```